# Railsコンテナにおける docker-compose up がエラーとなり起動できない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql, docker, docker-compose

開発環境にDockerを導入してRailsの開発を行いたいのですが、`docker-compose up` が正常に動作せず、どうすれば動作させることができるかの解決策や、原因として考えられることだけでもご教示いただければと思い、質問させていただきます。

#### 実現したいこと

**開発環境にDockerを使用し、Ruby on Railsの開発を行いたい。**
そのために、既存のRailsアプリをDockerにて起動し、ブラウザのlocalhostで見れるようにしたい。（既存のRailsアプリはWSLにて動作していました。この度、WSLでなくDockerで開発しようと思い立ちました）

下記のQiita記事を参考に実施しています。

[既存のRailsアプリにDockerを導入する手順](https://qiita.com/kenzoukenzou104809/items/b9e716204e0cd0cea447)
[丁寧すぎるDocker-composeによるrails5 + MySQL on Dockerの環境構築(Docker for Mac)](https://qiita.com/azul915/items/5b7063cbc80192343fc0#%E4%BD%95%E3%82%82%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E7%8A%B6%E6%85%8B%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89rails%E3%82%B5%E3%83%BC%E3%83%90%E3%83%BC%E3%81%A8mysql%E3%81%AE%E3%82%B3%E3%83%B3%E3%83%86%E3%83%8A%E3%82%92%E7%AB%8B%E3%81%A6%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%E3%82%B7%E3%82%A7%E3%83%AB2019-02-04%E8%BF%BD%E8%A8%98)

#### 使用環境

ツール：Docker Quickstart Terminal
VM：VirtualBox（Linux2.6/ 3.x/ 4.X(64bit)）
ホストOS：Windows10 Home

#### 現在の状態

１．Docker Quickstart Terminalを起動し、Dockerコマンドを打ち、動作することは確認しています。

２．Dockerfileとdocker-compose.ymlは以下のように記述し、`docker-compose build --no-cache` は正常に完了できました。その後、`docker-compose up` を実行したところでエラーが出ています。

＜エラーメッセージ＞

```
web：Could not locate Gemfile or .bundle/ directory と表示後、
　　　exited with code 10と表示されました。
```

３．webのみエラーが出ている様子です。調査中ですが、調べる時間があまりに長時間かかっているため、質問させていただいた次第です。（DBコンテナは起動しているようです）

※ホスト側のRailsアプリのディレクトリ
C:\mydev\myfavrest-app

※ターミナル起動時のカレントディレクトリ
/c/Program Files/Docker Toolbox

※docker-compose upを実行時のディレクトリ（カレントディレクトリからRailsアプリのディレクトリへ移動しました）
C:\mydev\myfavrest-app
→ディレクトリ構造（1階層目のみ）

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 ユーザ名 197121    0  4月 30 20:42 app/
drwxr-xr-x 1 ユーザ名 197121    0  5月 24 10:44 bin/
drwxr-xr-x 1 ユーザ名 197121    0  5月 24 10:44 config/
-rw-r--r-- 1 ユーザ名 197121  130  4月 11 18:36 config.ru
drwxr-xr-x 1 ユーザ名 197121    0  5月 24 10:44 db/
-rw-r--r-- 1 ユーザ名 197121  416  5月 24 17:37 docker-compose.yml
-rw-r--r-- 1 ユーザ名 197121  640  5月 24 16:50 Dockerfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 ユーザ名 197121 2728  5月 24 16:54 Gemfile
-rw-r--r-- 1 ユーザ名 197121    0  5月 24 10:44 Gemfile.lock
drwxr-xr-x 1 ユーザ名 197121    0  4月 11 18:36 lib/
drwxr-xr-x 1 ユーザ名 197121    0  4月 22 23:39 log/
-rw-r--r-- 1 ユーザ名 197121   71  4月 11 18:36 package.json
drwxr-xr-x 1 ユーザ名 197121    0  4月 29 21:39 public/
-rw-r--r-- 1 ユーザ名 197121  227  4月 11 18:36 Rakefile
-rw-r--r-- 1 ユーザ名 197121 5707  5月 13 23:07 README.md
drwxr-xr-x 1 ユーザ名 197121    0  5月 24 10:44 spec/
drwxr-xr-x 1 ユーザ名 197121    0  4月 11 18:36 storage/
drwxr-xr-x 1 ユーザ名 197121    0  4月 29 21:39 tmp/
drwxr-xr-x 1 ユーザ名 197121    0  4月 11 18:36 vendor/
```

#### Dockerfile

```
FROM ruby:2.6.5
# apt-utils関連のエラーを表示させないようにする
ENV DEBCONF_NOWARNINGS yes
RUN apt-get update -qq && \
    apt-get install -y --no-install-recommends build-essential \ 
                       libpq-dev \        
                       nodejs \
                       && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

# 作業ディレクトリの作成、設定
RUN mkdir /myapp
WORKDIR /myapp

# ホスト側（ローカル）のGemfileを追加する
COPY Gemfile /myapp/Gemfile
COPY Gemfile.lock /myapp/Gemfile.lock

# Gemfileのbundle install
RUN bundle install
COPY . /myapp
```

#### docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: '3'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: password
      MYSQL_DATABASE: myfavrest-app_development
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
  web:
    build: .
    command: bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'
    volumes:
      - .:/myapp
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    links:
      - db
    depends_on:
      - db
```

#### database.yml

```yaml
default: &default
  adapter: mysql2
  encoding: utf8
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>
  username: mydev
  password: password
  host: db
  socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock

development:
  <<: *default
  database: myfavrest-app_development

（test以下略）
```

#### Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.6.5'
gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.4.4', '< 0.6.0'
（以下略）
```

#### Gemfile.lock

Gemfile.lockは何も書かれていません。（中身は全て削除しました。）

#### エラー発生時の画面キャプチャ（webコンテナのエラー）

[image: 実行画面１]

並行して調査中ではございますが、お力添えいただきたい次第です。
不足情報等ございましたら追加しますので、お手数をおかけしますが、ご指摘いただけますと幸いです。
どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。
なお、teratailでの回答が得られない状況のため、こちらのサイトにも質問させていただいております。teratailで進展があり次第、こちらのサイトにもすぐ状況更新させていただきます。
https://teratail.com/questions/264199

Comment: TAMA.O さん、マルチポスト先の明記ありがとうございます。スタック・オーバーフローではマルチポストの禁止自体はしていませんが、回答者のために明記して欲しいというお願いを[しています](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/2418/19110)。また回答者の助けにするためのマルチポストコメントを[行ってくださる方もいます](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3087/19110)。以上 2 点ご承知おきくださると幸いです。

Comment: ご教示いただきありがとうございます。マルチポストという考え方があるということは知りませんでした。サイトによっては禁止のところがあるということですよね。今後留意するように致します。

Comment: Dockerfile が置いてあるディレクトリにおいて `tree -L 1` コマンドを実行した結果を質問文に追記してくださいませんでしょうか？　とりあえず Gemfile が Dockerfile に記載されているパスにあるのか確認したいです。

Comment: コメントいただきありがとうございます。
treeが入っていなかったのでls -lの結果を質問文に記載しました。（Dockerfileの直前の箇所です）Gemfileも指定のパスにある想定でした。
treeも後ほど導入します。

Comment: ありがとうございます。`ls` でも見たい結果は見れたのでこのままで結構です。次に考えたいのはホスト側のファイルシステムへの書き込みに失敗しているかどうかですね……。たとえば `docker run -it --rm -v "$(pwd):/myapp" ruby:2.6.5 /bin/sh` でシェルを立ち上げた後、`cd /myapp`、`echo test > foobar` などとして、`/myapp` 経由でホスト側へのファイル作成が成功するか試してみてくださいませんでしょうか。

Comment: @nekketsuuu  ありがとうございます。仕事中により返信遅くなりました。ご記載の手順で実施し、ファイル作成は成功できました。 `# echo test > foobar
# ls  foobar`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

自己解決しました。
volumeのマウントがきちんとできていないことが原因でした。
`C:\mydev\myfavrest-app`で作業していましたが、そこがvirtualboxの共有フォルダに含まれていませんでした。インストールしたあとデフォルト設定のまま特にいじっていなかったため、`c:\Users`しか共有されていませんでした。

virtualboxのdefaultマシンの、「設定」→「共有フォルダ」で、`C:\mydev`を`c/mydev`という名前で共有する設定を追加したところ、正常動作を確認することができました。